# How to add a specialised content editor web part to the web part gallery?

Tags: deployment, content-editor-web-part, web-part-gallery

I would like to add in the web part catalog for the whole farm a specialized version of the content editor web part.

Actually, I want to allow all site managers to drop a content editor that contains a custom script.

I know I could create a custom web part, but it requires a lot of stuff that the oob content editor web part could handle.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

- Create your CEWP (saved as .dwp)
- Edit it as you like
- Export the web part
- Create a SharePoint Project in VS
- Create a Module
- Add the dwp file

**Module** (CustomCEWP):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="CustomCEWP" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
        <File Path="CustomCEWP\CustomCEWP.dwp" Url="CustomCEWP.dwp" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
            <Property Name="Group" Value="My Web Parts" />
        </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

**CustomCEWP.dwp**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Custom Content Editor</Title>
  <FrameType>Default</FrameType>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>  
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge>
  <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
  <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>
  <ContentLink xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
  <Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[​​  <script>console.log('oh, hai');</script>​]]></Content>
  <PartStorage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor" />
</WebPart>
```

Comment: Sorry, this will not work for whole farm. But you can create a solution with it a Feature and a Module. Let me update...

Comment: I've created a VS project that deploy my dwp. But I hoped there were a simpler solution.

Comment: I updated the answer at least, maybe someone else can benefit from it.

Comment: You could of course be very sneaky and copy/paste a feature directory directly into the <Hive>\TEMPLATE\FEATURES folder. That way you could at least edit your dwp file without having to build it all the time (or compress into wsp manually).  
If SPSite is close enough you could also upload directly to Web Part Gallery ( /_catalogs/wp/Forms/AllItems.aspx )

Comment: I ended up by creating a custom wsp file with this simple module. This is working, but a bit disappointing .

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you didn't accept my answer right away and let it "stay open" for other interests. I would love to see a neater solution myself.

Comment: Ok, let's wait few days in this case.

Comment: No better solution. I've mark yours as answer

Answer (score 1):

Was just looking into this. While it's not farm-wide and will only work at the site collection level (which is all I needed it for), it still may be useful for others that come across this thread.

http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/sp2010-exporting-and-importing-web.html

Comment: Sadly doesn't work cross language